# Background Image Scroll IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

1230sharp.com

For some reason the background images are scrolling with the website.  I have the value "background position:fixed" and background-attachment:"local" and I'm getting the same issue.

1230sharp.com/#services  - any suggestions?

Comment: please post the browser you are using to test.. ie7 or ie8? etc

Comment: ie 8. Thank you, David!

Comment: i dont see any difference between ie8 and chrome? is there something i am missing? in addition background-attachment local is only supported in ie9, chrome,safari, opera but not in firefox or ie8

Comment: If you notice, the background on IE scrolls with the page (black backgrounds), and on chrome it does not...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so because ie8 doesnt support `background-attachment:local`

it uses `background-attachment:fixed`. If you remove that you should be fine.

Meaning do not use either one for `.section` div or anywhere you dont want to the background to scroll.

I removed both of them and it worked for me in chrome and ie8 :)

### UPDATED

You can actually switch to `background-attachment: scroll` instead of `local` and that should work as well for both ie8 and chrome and others.

source [**here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/backgroundattachment.html)

### EDITED

Use `background-attachment: scroll !important;` that way it should overwriting the `local` in current browsers like chrome and remember to clear your cache

Comment: I removed it and it does not work...?  It's like that now. Does it work for you?

Comment: im on your 1230sharp.com and it still has background-attachment local

Comment: its because its overwriting it in the inline style code use `!important` and just so you it works in ie8 now it defaults to `background-attachment:scroll` make sure to clear your cache